# will a 32-bit web application run as WOW64 on a 64-bit server?

Tags: iis, wow64

I need to know if a web application deployed in a 64-bit server runs as a WOW64 process or a 64-bit process if the web application's pages are compiled as PE 32/x86 ?

I mean I have read a lot about normal console applications or executables with PE 32/x86 run as WOW64 on 64-bit servers. But what about web applications( all i can compile is the pages which are dlls)? The only process I can think of is w3wp.exe for web apps. Please explain. I am confused.

Thanks in advance

Vineeth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you simply generate a test application, deploy it on you server and then use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to check the details?

Comment: Thanks for that. That really helped me in knowing which process is going on. But I also need to know why? I mean if my website is 32-bit compiled targeted for CPUs with x86 architecture, still bcoz the pages are just dlls and the kind of process depends on the executable and not the dependent dlls it uses a 64-bit process. Am I correct in the last sentence. Correct me if I am wrong. Also would like it if u could explain a bit. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert in this subject. I switch to a 32 bit IIS process, whenever I have the need to, only. E.g. I have an application that connects to an Oracle DB and only the 32-bit-drivers are working, so I switched to a 32-bit app pool.